# Magento 2 Where ship-station (shipping charge) details will save at magento side?

Tags: magento2, database, orders, totals, shipment

I have installed and configured **Auctane_Api** ship-station module to magento2. Whenever I placed the orders those information populated at
ship-station portal successfully. After processed shipment fulfillment at `ship-station portal` where these details `(Tracking Number, Shipping Cost/Rate, Shipping Carrier)` will save at magento side database tables?

Can any one clarify/help where those details will save in database table?

[image: Magento with Shipstation]

Comment: It calls the api with returns an XML, the tracking details from XML are then obtained and saving magento shipment.

Comment: @MilindSingh I think she is asking about database tables?

Comment: @MilindSingh can you help me on https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251888/magento-2-order-status-not-changing