# Magento 2 order status not changing?

Tags: magento2, orders, shipping-methods, order-status

We installed and configured `Auctane_Api (2.0.18)` ship-station module to `magento2` Whenever we placed the orders those information populated at ship-station portal successfully. After processed shipment fulfillment at ship-station portal below points not happening

1. Except **cost/rate** `Tracking Number,Shipping Carrier` details only saved  &
2. order status also still showing `progress` instead of `complete`?

The below image showing the settings of shipstation portal end.

[image]

please suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few possibilities that order status is not changing.

1.You have made some modifications in Auctane Shipstation Shipment Model file **app/code/community/Auctane/Api/Model/Action/Shipnotify.php**.
Try to use fresh shipstation extension.

2.Your Magento 2 store is in maintainance mode or sometimes in production mode it breaks, try to test in developer mode.

3.Check any extension you recently installed having these events:  sales_order_shipment_save_after or sales_order_shipment_track_save_after
Disable these events from **etc/di.xml** or simple disable those extensions.

4.Check var/exception.log and find recent exception related to shipment.

FYI - shipping cost and rates do not save in magento by shipstation.
you can only view , shipping carrier and tracking number in magento orders.

Also there is a feature that prevents ShipStation from updating a marketplace that an order has been “Shipped”. You can create an Automation Rule to apply this setting to your orders that import by going to Account Settings > Automation Rules > Create a Rule > Only apply this rule to orders that match a specific criteria > choose your Magento store > Add an Action > select Do Not Notify Marketplace from the dropdown menu > Save Changes.

Still , if you face issue you may open support case on shipstation.

Comment: Hi @Rajneesh Gupta thanks for providing valuable information i have  verified and did all 4 points which u have provide for order status (complete) but no luck.  in the exception.log not getting any related information and shipment events didn't used ...is there any alternative idea to fix this issue regarding order status

Comment: hi @Rajneesh Gupta is there any possibility to call additional API to fetch shipping cost from ship-station portal for respected order? please advise

Comment: You can cross check it by dumping the xml of shipstation in shipnotify model . Create a log to dump it as the data sent from shipstation when you mark order as shipped on shipstation. I think if they sent shipping rates in their shipment xml , you can set it in Magento shipment. I hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi @rajneeshgupta   I voided my shipment for order XXXXYYY in Shipstation and re-shipped using a different service. I was hoping Shipstation would update the Magento order accordingly with the new tracking number, but this did not happen. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: Hi @Nagaraju Kasa
i have not done it before , void order and again ship.